# Как "правильнее" работать с QMap C++

Tags: c++, qt, map

Как лучше писать так:

```
auto it = labels_map["Level"] = new QLabel();
it->setText("Уровень: " + QString::number(player->get_level()));
grid_layout->addWidget(it,0,0);

it = labels_map["Exp"] = new QLabel();
it->setText("Опыт: " + QString::number(player->get_xp()) + "/" + 
QString::number(player->get_xp_for_next_lvl()));
grid_layout->addWidget(it,1,0);
```

или так:

```
labels_map["Level"] = new QLabel();
labels_map["Level"]->setText("Уровень: " + QString::number(player-
>get_level()));
grid_layout->addWidget(labels_map["Level"],0,0);

labels_map["Exp"] = new QLabel();
labels_map["Exp"]->setText("Опыт: " + QString::number(player->get_xp()) + 
"/" + QString::number(player->get_xp_for_next_lvl()));
grid_layout->addWidget(labels_map["Exp"],1,0);
```

или разницы особой нет и можно писать как мне удобнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый раз когда вы используете оператор `[]` происходит поиск элемента в контейнере. Его сложность для `QMap` O(log n). На вашем месте я бы писал так:

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel();
label ->setText("Text");
layout->addWidget(label, 0, 0);
QMap["Level"] = label;
```

С остальными оценками сложности можете ознакомиться [здесь](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#algorithmic-complexity)

Comment: Тогда следующий label будет добавляться таким кодом?
   `label = new QLabel();
    label->setText("Text2");
    grid_layout->addWidget(label, 1, 0);
    labels_map["Level2"] = label;`

Comment: Можно и так, но я бы завел две переменные с осмысленными именами. А еще лучше, вынес этот кусок кода в отдельный метод